# Ubuntu 18.04, issue with headless desktop and remote access

Tags: gnome, headless

I have an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS desktop install that I use as a Tor relay. It's using a mini-PC with an Intel j4105 (integrated graphics).

I am wanting to have it not connected via HDMI, as I don't have enough ports to have it connected 24/7. When connecting via remote desktop tools the Gnome desktop is buggy and isn't really usable. Eventually I have to connect HDMI, logout of the user, then log back in for it to work properly again. I read that it has to do with it not being connected to any monitor. I tried installing X11 emulator drivers on Ubuntu so I could connect to a virtual desktop but after doing so I couldn't boot fully (it would get stuck on the purple startup screen), so I reinstalled and instead bought a $7 "HDMI Dummy plug" off of Amazon so it thinks a 1080p monitor is connected, but this issue still persists.

Here is what happens when connected using NoMachine. The same happens with any remote desktop tools like TeamViewer. (none of the icons/buttons on the desktop or toolbars are clickable)

https://i.imgur.com/GXxL7HO.gif

What should I do to get this to work properly headless? This is one of the guides I used and had the boot issue afterwards.
https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Fix_Ubuntu_Desktop_to_Boot_without_Monitor_Connected

I have experience with Linux in general, but I've almost never used desktop environments.

Thanks,

Comment: I tried my HDMI dummy plug again and it actually works now, not sure why it wasn't before, maybe the HDMI port connection was bad before.